# IOException handling in multiple methods

Tags: java, try-catch

Consider the following code

```
public class foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.read();
  }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass {
  private BufferedWriter verb;
  private String vFile;
  MyClass()
  {
    try {
      verb = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(vFile));
    } catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Internal error1");
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public void read()
  {
    // read a file and create an array
    verb.write("Array created");    // ERROR
  }
}
```

As you can see the `write` is not placed in a `try..catch` block. I can write a catch for that, but `MyClass` has many methods and `verb.write` is used heavily. I also can write `public void read() throws IOException` to throw the exception to the the caller, `main()`. Still I have to put `mc.read()` in a `try..catch` block. Since MyClass has numerous methods, then I have to put all of them in a catch block in the `main()`.

So, is there a better way to handle that? Is it possible to redirect all exceptions related to `verb` to the constructor, `MyClass()` where a try..catch is defined?

Comment: OT: Why on earth you have a method named ***read*** that actually does the opposite: ***writes***??

Comment: "Redirect to the constructor" ? What do you mean? The constructor always executes first, and your `read` method that writes gets executed later. How do you imagine that you could "redirect" something that happens later to something that happened earlier? Time travel?

Comment: Please see the updated post. The `read()` reads an input file and then I write a message in a verbose file.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: OK. So what is the good way to handle that? As I said, in multiple methods, I want to use `verb.write()`.

Comment: @mahmood I don't see much sens in the question. You want to redirect exception and handle it later, but don't what to handle it in your main method. What I've understood incorrectly?

Comment: As I said multiple times, I use `verb.write` many times in many methods of MyClass. It is a pain and error prone if I have to put them in try..catch. If that is the only way, then OK... I asked to see if there a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make your own "safe" wrapper around `BufferedWriter` (for that matter, any kind of [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)) and handle I/O errors there:

```
class SafeWriter {
    private final Writer writer;
    public SafeWriter(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }
    public void write(int n) {
        try {
            writer.write(n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
    }
    public void write(String s) {
        try {
            writer.write(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
    }
    ... // Provide wrappers for other methods here
    private void handleException(IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use `write` methods on your new class to handle exceptions in a uniform way inside the class:

```
private SafeWriter verb;
...
verb = new SafeWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(vFile)));
```